# PHP - jQuery - Comet chat

Tags: php, jquery, comet

I am looking for a solution for PHP and comet. I would like to make a chat using Ajax to send the message. I call the function using jQuery and send data, it is simple.

But the problem is in retrieving new messages. How to retrieve messages using the new solution comet? I need a simple example.
I am looking for a solution for non-commercial use - for free.

Comment: php isn't really the ideal language for comet applications.

Comment: What would you use for the technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I would tell you to use Node.js as your backend technology.

Here's a more lengthy explanation: [Creating a live checkers-like web app with PHP, JS, CSS and HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022235/creating-a-live-checkers-like-web-app-with-php-js-css-and-html/6022368#6022368)

Answer (score 0):

if you're set on using php, you can use a comet server which will sit on top of apache (or whatever server you prefer) and proxy any non-comet requests to it. I've used one called [streamhub](http://www.stream-hub.com/) which is written in java.